# Sorl-thumbnail--> Image height is not equals to the given height

Tags: django

After implementing the below code when i see image on frontend width is 430 but height not equals to th given height(250) instead it is 100

{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail recipe.image "430x250" as thumb %}

{% endthumbnail %}

Comment: what about intrinsic image size when you inspect image, you could have CSS rules that resize image

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following strategy to render the image with its given height and width. Usage of examples are mentioned in the [document](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template.html).

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail recipe.image "430x250" crop="center" as img %}
    <img src="{{ img.url }}" width={% firstof img.width "430" %} height={% firstof img.height "250" %} alt=""/>
{% endthumbnail %}
```